# How to get all games that user has played while using Discord with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Is there any way to get all games that user has played while using Discord?
So based on that I can give them specific roles.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to store them, there is no history of games played available in the API